# Progress bar .GIF Image Freeze in IE Browser when Data Rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using progress .GIF image when my web page is refresh or any postback is happen I show progress bar and it's working fine but when the data is render that time .GIF images freezes in IE Browser.

Following is html Code .

```
<div class='overlay' id="cleintSideOverlayMain">
<div class="modal-progress">
<div class="progress-bar">
<img id="OverlayImage" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my client side code when all data render .

```
$('#cleintSideOverlayMain').css('display', 'none');
```

I also tried with.
1) spin.js
2) Use SetTimeout();
3) Use Iframe.
4) HTML5 Animation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the rendering is done with Javascript: Javascript uses single threading. That means that the UI and your rendering uses the same thread and while the rendering is working, the UI is blocked. That will freeze your progress bar.

> When executing scripts in an HTML page, the page becomes unresponsive
>   until the script is finished.

**There are currently two workarounds I know about:**

1. If your users only use [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) you can use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers). You can then use another thread for the rendering (a worker thread).
2. If possible you can render on the client side and only send the result to the browser by using AJAX.